# How cascade works for maps in JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Consider the following case,

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)   // unidirectional
@MapKeyClass(KeyEntityImpl.class)
private Map<KeyEntity,ValueEntity> map=new HashMap<>();
```

How is the above going to work, is `KeyEntity` removed on removing an item from the map or the `ValueEntity` or both?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer from docs.

> The `OneToMany` annotation may be used within an embeddable class
>   contained within an entity class to specify a relationship to a
>   collection of entities. If the relationship is bidirectional, the
>   `mappedBy` element must be used to specify the relationship field or
>   property of the entity that is the owner of the relationship.
>
> When the collection is a `java.util.Map`, the cascade element and the
>   `orphanRemoval` element apply to the map value.

Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html